# Why MySQL database registering blank entiry?

Tags: php, mysql, imp

I'm working with electric imp + MySQL database. I'm trying to pass my imp values to MySQL using PHP but it's showing up blank entries, any idea why? I tried everything but can't figure out what's happening.

**PHP**

```
<?php

// Set your default timezone
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');
define('DB_USER', 'db_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db_pass');
define('DB_HOST', 'db_host');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('value');

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//get info
$status = $data['status'];

if (!$db_selected)
{
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST ['status'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO imp (status) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "<h5>Message Successfully Sent!</p></h5>";

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Because `$value` is empty?

Comment: Are you posting a `status` value?  Also note that your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection attacks**.

Comment: Also you mix mysqli and mysql functions.

Comment: @u_mudder `$value` in my php?

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis is right - you are using [mysql](http://se1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions, but opened a [mysqli](http://se1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) database!

Comment: you have many errors already given by the previous commands, but what I would like to add is that I think you need to rethink the whole process of what your doing and then try to write your code

Comment: @kostasMitsarakis so i can use only mysqli?

Comment: @Attitude-24: You have to choose one of the two.  Though, honestly, there should be an error message from attempting to mix the two.  I suspect there's more information you're not sharing with us.

Comment: @David I have only this php script and other scripts are from Electric imp Agent and Device which i haven't posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following using PDO and prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'your_host');
define('DB_NAME', 'your_db_name');
define('DB_USER', 'your_username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_password');

try {
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

    $jsondata = file_get_contents('value');

    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    //get info
    $status = $data['status'];
    $value = $_POST['status'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO imp (status) VALUES (:status)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':status'=>$value));

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "<h5>Message Successfully Sent!</p></h5>"; 
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```